# Find and replace in multiple files from a list in a .txt file

Tags: replace, cmd, find

I have a folder with multiple html files. In each file there is a string 'replacethistext' that I need to replace from a list in a txt file.

ie

```
   html1.                textline1
   html2                 textline2
   html3 etc             textline3
```

There must be some application to do this but all the find an replace tools i have won't load from a list but will replace a string with the same text...

Comment: Jefferson, welcome to SO. This is probably not the right forum to get software suggestions. Answers here tend to focus on making the tools you  already have at your disposal work to accomplish your particular need. Most people come here to get help writing there own programs, not finding others. That being said, your questions would fair better if you told us what tools you do have (operating system, programming interfaces). If that's not the direction you want to go, I might try this question over at the Power Users stack exchange.

Comment: Well I'd take command line instructions every day.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend adding the cmd tag to your question (assuming your OS is Windows). Before you do that, however, I would spend at least a little time trying to write a cmd line solution yourself, then update your question to include what you've tried. If you do that, you've got a great chance of getting a quick solution. If you don't do that, then you'll most likely get a lot of flack about SO not being a code writing service and there's a good chance your post will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to use `msr.exe` in `tools` directory in **my open project**: https://github.com/qualiu/msr with your system type (`Windows`/`Cygwin`/`CentOS`/`Ubuntu`/`Fedora`) and bits (32/64) version.

**For your case**, you probably need a loop, such as:

- Windows, if run in command window: Use `msr.exe` (64-bit) or `msr-Win32.exe` (32-bit)

  `for /L %k in (1,1,3) do msr -p my-file-%k.html -x "replacethistext" -o "textline%k" -R`
- Windows, if run **in a batch (*.bat) file**: Use `%%k` other than `%k`:

  `for /L %%k in (1,1,3) do msr -p my-file-%%k.html -x "replacethistext" -o "textline%%k" -R`
- Linux: Cygwin/CentOS/Ubuntu/Fedora: Use `msr.cygwin` or `msr.gcc48` (64-bit) or `msr-i386.gcc48` (32-bit)

  `for ((k = 1; k <= 3; k++)); do msr -p my-file-$k.html -x "replacethistext" -o "textline$k" -R ; done`